# AWS S3 Lambda touch on fetch.

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

Is it possible to manipulate data before it is returned when using an S3 link. For example if I hit mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile could have a Lambda function run and manipulate a file before it is returned?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible -- the data will be returned as it actually exists in Amazon S3.

However, you might consider using [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/coming-soon-lambda-at-the-edge/) (in preview at the time of writing this answer). This serves content via Amazon CloudFront and allows an AWS Lambda function to be run before the data is returned. (Actually, it can run code before fetching data from S3 *and* after receiving the data.)

Comment: Thanks for your input here. Very helpful. Im trying to stream a file (feed certain bytes) directly through some scalable aws functionality vs having to set up an ec2 instance and worry about scaling from there. I wanted to try and keep the urls to S3 that my app relies on the same but manipulate he streaming data on request.

Comment: Feel free to create another question with more details and you might receive suitable answers based upon the type of data you are streaming and the type of manipulation. It could be that tools like Cloudinary or Amazon Kinesis would fit, but it depends upon the use-case.